# When exactly is the WinAPI drawing content to the screen?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, winapi, imgui

I have a setup where I am taking images with a camera from my monitor/screen. The camera is positioned infront of the screen... Camera and monitor are connected to the same PC.

On the screen I am moving a white rectangle on a black background in meandering shape. After each move I am taking an image. My application is written in C++. And the OS is Windows 11.

Image aquisition and GUI are running on different threads. I am synchronizing the threads through a conditional variable. Now I am encountering the problem that I am never really sure when the GUI is updating the screen. My rectangle skips positions.

I need something that gives me the feedback that the rectangle has been drawn. If that is not possible is there something like that the display manager queue is empty? Just so that I can be 100% sure that everything has been drawn.

I have tryed QT and ImGUI. In QT after the paintEvent the drawing through a painter is not drawn directly to the screen. I know that the display manager is gathering changes togather and draw those to the screen. It seem like I do not have access to the display manager. Since ImGUI is working in direct mode I thought it would be better. But unfortunately I encountered the same issue.

Comment: Monitors usually have a delay of a few milliseconds, even if the code says the screen is redrawn, the monitor may still be buffering, you have to measure this delay and compensate it anyway.

Comment: *I am never really sure when the GUI is updating the screen. My rectangle skips positions. I need something that gives me the feedback that the rectangle has been drawn* -- Maybe you already have this as a setup, but are you debugging using dual monitors?  With what I've experienced, if you want to see updates at the same time you're debugging a GUI app, a dual monitor debugging setup would be advantageous so that you see the drawing done when stepping with the debugger.

Comment: @AhmedAEK: If you mean adding a delay for the monitor (HW) delay. I agree with you. But I would not like to add a delay for the the time that the display manager think it has "enough" changes to send to the monitor.  This information should be available to the user somehow...

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: I have a dual monitor setup. Visual Studio is opened on one monitor and my rectangles on the primary monitor. I also did not set any debug break points inside the GUI code so that I am sure that the debugger does not interfere with the GUI loop.